# How to convert non-PSD matrix to PSD matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a mixed-integer optimization problem with the following constraint matrix $Q_1$:

\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{array}

I have the constraint $x^T Q_1 x=0$ where the upper bounds of $x$ are $[10,7,8,1,1,1]$ and the lower bounds are $[1,1,1,0,0,0]$, and $x$ is the vector to be optimized.

In order to run the optimization, the matrix has to be positive semi-definite. Is there a matrix that will produce the same result, but is positive semi-definite?

For some context:

The entire optimization problem is to minimize $d^T x + \frac{1}{2}x^T Q x$ where $Q$ is the following:

\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{array}

And $d^T$ is [$\begin{array}{cccccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 7 & 8 \end{array}$].

So the function equates to:
$-((10-x_1)x_4+(7-x_2)x_5+(8-x_3)x_6)+x_1x_4+x_2x_5+x_3x_6$ with the constraint that $x_1x_4=x_2x_5+x_3x_6$.

I.e., I'm trying to minimize a "residual" and maximize a sum. This is an allocation problem where $x_1$ is the amount allocated to a buyer, and $x_2$ and $x_3$ are amounts allocated to a seller. $x4,x5,x6$ are variables where I decided if I should allocate at all.

I'm looking for a solution that produces $x=[10,7,3,1,1,1]$ or something Pareto-equivalent.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the entire optimization problem (e.g., the function you're trying to optimize -- you've only given us the constraints). You could add a large multiple of the identity to $Q$ to make it positive semidefinite -- that changes the optimal value, but in a very simple way. However, I feel like I don't know enough about the problem you're trying to solve to know if this transformation is "OK".

Comment: @NathanielJohnston I changed my question to include the entire problem. I decided that quadratic programming w/ a quadratic constraint is the best fit for this problem, but if you can see an easier way by all means let me know. I'm pretty new to optimization, and my decision was based largely on googling.

Answer (score 1):

Your  problem is not convex.  In particular,  you're likely to have many local minima rather than just a single one.  Therefore it's unlikely that you could  "convert" the problem into a convex one in any simple way.
You might look at global optimization software.

By the way, I think the optimal solution is $x_1=10,x_2=7,x_3=8,x_4=1,x_5=1,x_6=3/8$

Comment: Thanks @Robert-Israel --you reminded me to mention that this is a mixed-integer problem. I am currently using a population-based global optimization algorithm like you recommended, but was trying to test out if a quadratic programming approach would work as well.

Comment: This gives optimum $20$ and the solution seems not to be unique, in fact there is a $1$-parameter family of solutions: $x_1=10,x_2=7,x_3=8,x_4=1,x_5=t,x_6=\frac{10-7t}{8}$